# How to change the style of a button when pressed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to change the style of a button when I click on it while the app is running.

Like I have a button with a grey color, I want it to change to red when I click on it?
I tried to do it with the Click event, however the button still shows the default effect when I hover over the button.

Here is the WPF code I used.

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="btnExitDef">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF1E1E1E"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFD6D6D6"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        CornerRadius="0"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        Padding="0"
                        BorderBrush="#000">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">

                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#fff"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

<Button Height="35" Width="45" Name="btnExit" Content="✕"  BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Click="btnExit_Click" Style="{StaticResource btnExitDef}"/>
```

Comment: have you tried to use IsPressed instead of IsMouseOver to change the color on click? <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#fff"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to edit the button's style and add another Trigger for the `IsPressed` property.

```
<Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
</Trigger>
```